# Exception syntaxis error: unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

Я пишу свою программу бот на node js, используя electron и react. Суть ее заключается в том, что она должна работать 24/7, делая определенные запросы. Все работает хорошо, программа сутками работает, однако редко раз в неделю появляется неизвестная ошибка: Exception syntaxis error: unexpected token. После token ничего нет, поэтому и не могу понять в чем проблема. Грубо говоря node js говорит "Ищи сам". Если кто сталкивался с такой проблемой или знает где копать, или как node js заставить сказать, где он сломался, прошу помочь.

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

VS code никаких синтаксических ошибок не показывает.
Показать код не могу, т.к. там 8К строк кода.

P.S. Слышал про пробелы нулевой ширины, но в коде вроде как их так и не нашел.

Comment: Вообще, когда процесс nodejs падает, он в консоль выводит стектрейс. А судя по ошибке, есть какое то ответвление, например if else в котором как раз и допущена синтаксическая ошибка, либо входящие данные не соответствуют ожиданиям

Comment: Просто это уже готовый exe билд, поэтому консоли нет. Предлагаете в dev консольном режиме ее погонять, пока не получу это? Просто не знаю на какой символ или его отсутствие он может ругаться. VS Code говорит, что все окей

Comment: Если нет логов, по которым можно понять, какую последнюю операцию выполнял процесс, то запуск в консольном режиме, мне кажется единственным возможным вариантом отловить ошибку.

Comment: @SwaD А как думаете насчет костыля main файл весь обернуть в try catch и сохранить в лог результат ошибки, или при падении процесса он не сработает?

Comment: Можно еще попробовать запустить процесс так `main.exe >> log.txt`, но если при сборке в exe все выводы были обрезаны, то результата можно и не увидеть... Оборачивать все в try catch не самая хорошая идея, т.к. если ошибка в асинхронной функции, то она отловлена не будет

Comment: А можно подробнее про это? Я так понимаю, что в log.txt придет ошибка, как в консоли, но не очень понял как так запустить. Просто в консоли vs code запускать не очень хочется, ибо если свернуть vs, то через пару часов работа программы как будто замораживается, надо держать постоянно открытым

Comment: Создайте ярлык от вашего main.exe, в ярлыке в поле объект будет указан ваш exe, туда дописываете `>> log.txt` (Это вывод всей консольной информации в log.txt). Возможно, при падении выводится еще что то, но оно не влезает в стандартное окно ошибки винды. Например если выводит ошибку в консоль, то это объект у которого есть ключи message и stack. Message вы видите, а стек уже не печатается... Если запуск идет в виде службы, то изменить параметры запуска службы.

Comment: Понял, спасибо попробую! Еще, может будет интересно, нарыл библиотеку для обработки ошибок "electron-unhandled", уже протестировал, она позволяет обрабатывать любые ошибки и записывать их в лог самому или отправлять на сервер куда либо. Попробую двумя способами, спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решил с помощью библиотеки `electron-unhandled` для `electron`

```
const unhandled = require( 'electron-unhandled' );
unhandled({
    logger: (error) => {
        // Здесь получаем все ошибки из нашего main процесса (Даже те, где нет try catch)
    },
    showDialog: false // Запретить показывать окно ошибки Windows 
});
```

Таким образом я понял, что в окне ошибки просто не писалась вся информация, которая нужна, чтобы исправить ошибку. В этом же случае мы получаем полный объект ошибки и можем сохранить ее в лог, при этом приложение зависать не будет, как в случае вывода ошибки в окно.

Очень полезная библиотека для отладки своего приложения electron. Теперь все какие-либо ошибки в коде приходят мне в телеграмм бота и я могу оперативно их исправить.